# How can I call git in Capistrano 3.7.1, since strategy.git doesn't work anymore?

Tags: git, rubygems, capistrano, capistrano3

I've update capistrano gem from 3.6.1 -> 3.7.1.

I have the following code in one of my tasks:

`strategy.git "push #{fetch(:git_remote, 'origin')} #{tag_name}"`

Now with the changes and requiring the SCM::GIT plugin, the strategy variable doesn't exist anymore.

How can I access the git command/object now? And what would be considered the right away of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `strategy.git` ever did was execute the `git` command. So this is equivalent:

```
execute :git, "push #{fetch(:git_remote, 'origin')} #{tag_name}"
```